# Static SharedPreference NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jdbc, sharedpreferences

I am trying to populate dbname in a jdbc string using shared preferences. The error that I get is

```
03-06 15:46:25.941: E/AndroidRuntime(3605): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vr/activities/DatabaseConnection
```

The JDBC connectivity works perfectly but cannot make it to work with shared preferences.

Here is my code:

public class DatabaseConnection extends Activity{

```
public static Context dbContext;
private static Connection connection = null;
private static DatabaseConnection instance = null;
private final static String DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";

public static class pro

{
    public static String dbname() {
        PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(dbContext);
        return preferenceHelper.getDBname();
    }
}
 static String dbname=pro.dbname();

private final static String DATABASE = dbname;


    //constructor
    public DatabaseConnection() {
    super();
    }
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.DatabaseConnection"
        android:label="@string/database_connection"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

PreferenceHelper is my SharedPreferences helper file and it works well with a couple of activities that I have in the app. preferenceHelper.getDBname() is also called in another activity and its working fine, so I know thats not the issue.
If I use a hard coded static string it works fine with the jdbc driver

```
private final static String DATABASE = "mydatabase";
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854): Process: com.vr PID: 1854
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vr/activities/DatabaseConnection
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at com.vr.activities.MaintenanceActivity$1$2$1LongOperation.doInBackground(MaintenanceActivity.java:91)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at com.vr.activities.MaintenanceActivity$1$2$1LongOperation.doInBackground(MaintenanceActivity.java:72)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-06 16:39:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     ... 4 more
03-06 16:39:59.920: W/ActivityManager(1274):   Force finishing activity com.vr/.activities.MaintenanceActivity
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace and point to the line in the code where it crashes.

Comment: what is your package name?  `com.vr.activities`?

Comment: i had to modify that to hide the actual package name

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` often happens when the initialization of the class at startup failed. Is there a related error before this error message in the log file?

Comment: Afraid not. There is no other error. except the stack trace in the post. Rest are all related to Sound pool because I am using a emulator

Comment: 03-06 16:39:59.910: E/SoundPool(1274): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg